# Download all my youtube playlists to separate folders using youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I am trying to use youtube-dl to download all my public playlists from youtube in Windows 7 using the following taken from the documentation:

```
youtube-dl -o "%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

but it only downloads my uploads.

I tried modifying using code found online to this

```
youtube-dl -citw "%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" "Userlink/playlists"
```

but now all it downloads is my favourites in the same directory as the executable. Can someone suggest what I need to change?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Downloading using youtube-dl as playlists

```
# Download as audio in respective folder
$youtube-dl -ic -o "~/Videos/Youtube-dl/audios/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s- %(title)s.%(ext)s" --yes-playlist --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0

# Download as video in respective folder
$youtube-dl -f best --ignore-errors -o "~/Videos/Youtube-dl/videos/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s- %(title)s.%(ext)s" --yes-playlist
```

ProTip: If you're on a linux system then use alias to set shortcuts like

```
# Download as audio in respective folder
$alias y.dl.audio='youtube-dl -ic -o "~/Videos/Youtube-dl/audios/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s- %(title)s.%(ext)s" --yes-playlist --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0'

# Download as video in respective folder
$alias y.dl.video='youtube-dl -f best --ignore-errors -o "~/Videos/Youtube-dl/videos/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s- %(title)s.%(ext)s" --yes-playlist'
```